# More performant Javascript game tick?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, requestanimationframe

```
installLoops() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}


loop() {
    this.now = Date.now();
    var delta  = this.now - this.last;
    this.last = this.now;

    this.dt = this.dt + delta;

    if (this.dt < this.rate) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
        return;
    } else {
        this.game.loop();
        this.draw();
        this.dt = this.dt - this.rate;
        this.game.loopKeyboardInput(this.key_pressed_map);
        this.key_pressed_map = {};
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}
```

I moved

```
this.game.loopKeyboardInput(this.key_pressed_map);
this.key_pressed_map = {};
```

to inside the block where the game loop is called, which improved my average from rate from 12.56 to 56+. However, in performance testing my framerate still drops down to 13 (lowest). (I'm not sure if this is happening because of the performance sampling).

How can I achieve a more performant tick code keeping my minimum frame rate high?

Comment: Questions about improving functioning code are more appropriate on [codereview.se]

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there.

Comment: Rather than re-binding every time you use `requestAnimationFrame` you could re-assign `loop` during the `installLoops` method as the bound function. `this.loop = this.loop.bind(this)`. Then you can just use `requestAnimationFrame(this.loop)` and avoid the overhead of generating a new function.

Comment: @jmoerdyk If the code is under-performing enough to be considered not working, they're better here.